# Automapper map object to xml template

Tags: c#, xml, automapper

I have the following object:

```
    public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Initials { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

And the following xml template:

```
<request>
<action></action>
<service></service>
<operation></operation>
<arguments>
    <ns0:Contact xmlns:ns0="http://www.test.com/types">         
        <ns0:Name/>
        <ns0:Surname />
        <ns0:Initials />            
        <ns0:Street/>
        <ns0:City/>
    </ns0:Contact>
</arguments>
<authentication>
    <user></user>
    <password />
    <role />
    <authenticated></authenticated>
    <company />
</authentication>
```

How can I use Automapper to map an contact to the contact element in the xml template?

Comment: You are trying to use a hammer to screw in a screw.

Comment: The real object is much more complicated. I can use automapper to map it to an object wich can be serialized to the provided xml. But I would like to know if it can be mapped directly to the template.

Comment: The point I was trying to make is that Automapper is the wrong tool for what you are wanting to do.  Automapper is desinged to move data from one class to another class in memory; what you are trying to do here is serialization, that requires a different tool.